# Why is it when I extract a method in Eclipse I get this strange method?

Tags: java, eclipse

In my main method of a pomodoro app that is very-much in progress, I have this code:

```
    ActionListener a9 = new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){

        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
        String currentTime = (String) dateFormat.format(new Date());

        combo2.append("You completed " + i + ""
        +  " pomodoros! At " + currentTime + " \n");
         Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
        }
      };


    Timer newTimer = new Timer(500, a9);
    newTimer.start();
    newTimer.setRepeats(false);
```

But when I use the "Extract  Method" functionality of eclipse, I get this piece outside the main:

```
private static void generatePomodoro(final JTextArea combo2) {
    ActionListener a9 = new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){

        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
        String currentTime = (String) dateFormat.format(new Date());

        combo2.append("You completed " + i + ""
        +  " pomodoros! At " + currentTime + " \n");
         Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
        }
      };

    Timer newTimer = new Timer(500, a9);
    newTimer.start();
    newTimer.setRepeats(false);
}
```

This doesn't do what I was hoping for(which is to let me run consecutive countdown timers) . & looks really cryptic to me.. where did the signature come from?

```
private static void generatePomodoro(final JTextArea combo2)
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you give the new method a name in the Eclipse dialog and set proper modifiers or just accepted whatever defaults were there?

Comment: @PM77-1 - I put in a new name in the dialog, but otherwise I accept whatever defaults occur. I guess I was overly hopeful it would do what i wanted

Comment: Extracting a method does not change code behavior, so if your `Timer` part was wrong before, it would remain this way after.

Comment: @PM77-1 - OK, understood  . Yeah you're right.  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Your `main` method has signature `public static void main(String[] args)` and when you try to use `Extract Method`, Eclipse keeps has to keep new method `static` thus it would be accessible from `main`. New function is also `private` because code prior to refactoring was inaccessible from outside anyway as well as it is a good practice to keep functions private.